# How to clear the interval in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am building a stopwatch by using `useState` hooks in react.js but while implementing pause functionality I have noticed that I am not able to clear the interval. I am new and I have tried many things but still it doesn't work. If anyone can help me fix the code or suggest me other way.

Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [stopwatch, setStopwatch] = useState({
    hour: 0,
    min: 0,
    sec: 0,
    secElapsed: 0,
    minElapsed: 0,
  });

  const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState({
    start: true,
    stop: false,
    pause: false,
    resume: false,
  });

  var interval = null;

  function onStart() {
    // i want to clear this interval when the onPause function is called
    var clrInt = setInterval(() => {
      setStopwatch(prevValue => {
        prevValue.secElapsed++;
        return {
          hour: Math.floor(prevValue.secElapsed / 3600),
          minElapsed: Math.floor((prevValue.secElapsed + 1) / 60),
          min: prevValue.minElapsed % 60,
          sec: prevValue.secElapsed % 60,
          secElapsed: prevValue.secElapsed,
        };
      });
    }, 1000);

    setButtonState(prevValue => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        start: false,
        pause: true,
        stop: true,
      };
    });
    interval = clrInt;
  }

  function onPause() {
    setButtonState(prevValue => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        pause: false,
        resume: true,
      };
    });

    // i want to clear the interval in onStart function here
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {stopwatch.hour < 10 ? '0' + stopwatch.hour : stopwatch.hour}:
        {stopwatch.min < 10 ? '0' + stopwatch.min : stopwatch.min}:
        {stopwatch.sec < 10 ? '0' + stopwatch.sec : stopwatch.sec}
      </h1>
      {buttonState.start ? <button onClick={onStart}>Start</button> : null}
      {buttonState.pause ? <button onClick={onPause}>Pause</button> : null}
      {buttonState.stop ? <button>Stop</button> : null}
      {buttonState.resume ? <button>Resume</button> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a variable inside the function component will run every time the component is rendered. You need to capture the interval in a useState like

```
var [intervalState, setIntervalState] = useState(null)

...

function onStart() {
   var clearInterval = setInterval(() => {
      ...
   })

   setIntervalState(clearInterval)
}
```

This will make sure your clearInterval value will persist across rerenders

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the interval fits into the component's state. Instead, I would use the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to keep it through the component's lifetime.

*Anyways*, it's good that you start thinking in hooks :)

A cleaner way is to implement something like [useInterval](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/):

```
const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true)

useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
}, isRunning ? 1000 : null)

const onPause = () => {
    // ...
    setIsRunning(false)
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l240mp2pm7?file=/src/index.js:256-362)'s a demo with an actual implementation of the hook.